# Regex match multiple instances

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have combined and minified multiple CSS files into one string, like this:

```
@import "path/to/file1";.my-class{font-size:24px;}@import "path/to/file2";
```

But now I want to "turn off" importing. So, I want to remove all instances of `@import "something";` and get this:

```
.my-class{font-size:4px;}
```

I am currently using this:

```
echo preg_replace("(@import \".*\";)", "", $minified_css);
```

But that replaces the whole string. i.e., It's not stopping at the first instance of `";` and restarting.

How do I get the regex to replace the individual `@import` instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should preferable use this regex,

```
@import\s+"[^"]+";
```

And remove it with empty string

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5eWS0/1)**

Also, in your regex `(@import \".*\";)` avoid using `(` `)` as you don't need to uselessly group your regex when you are replacing it with empty string. Also avoid usage of `.*` else it will greedily match everything possible and may give you unexpected results.

Try this PHP code snippet,

```
$minified_css = '@import "path/to/file1";.my-class{font-size:24px;}@import "path/to/file2";';
echo preg_replace('/@import\s+\"[^"]+\";/', '', $minified_css);
```

Prints,

```
.my-class{font-size:24px;}
```

I don't think you need to use global `g` modifier in `preg_replace` as that happens by default and you can control the replacement number by passing a third parameter. Also, you don't need to use `m` multiline modifier as we aren't use start/end anchors in our pattern.

**[PHP code demo](https://rextester.com/TCB19718)**

Comment: So, it's working as desired on regex101.com but not when I implement it in PHP. I am using `echo preg_replace('/@import\s+\"[^"]+\";/gm', '', $minified_css);`.

Comment: It works. Let me update my answer with a working PHP code snippet.

Comment: Updated my answer and if still it doesn't work for you, please try adding more details in your post with more sample data, so I can help pin point the main issue.

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the greedy `*` operator, which tries to match as much as possible.

Try using `.*?` (the lazy operator) instead of `.*`.